# Javascript - Loop through nested arrays and objects filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Trying to obtain all the arrays using a specific ideas. Not sure how to perform the filtering there but i figured i would ask here. Hopefully it's clear enough what i'm trying to do. Pretty much i have a list of courses and would like to get all the courses where level = 1.

```
 let courses = [{
               math:[{id:1,level_id:1,requirement:'1 Credit'}]
               spanish:[{id:5,level_id:1,requirement:'5 Credits'}] 
               technology:[{id:3,level_id:1,requirement:'2 Credits'}]
            }];
             
            let queryCoursesForLevelWhereIDMatches = 1
            
            let returnedArrays = courses.filter()
             
             console.log(returnedArrays);
```

Comment: Where's the callback to `filter` that is checking the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do something along the  lines of:

```js
function CourseMaster(courses = null){
  this.courses = courses;
  this.getMath = (byProp, byVal = null)=>{
    return this.courses.math.filter(o=>{
      let p = o.hasOwnProperty(byProp);
      if(byVal === null){
        return p;
      }
      return p && byVal === o[byProp];
    });
  }
  this.getSpanish = (byProp, byVal = null)=>{
    return this.courses.spanish.filter(o=>{
      let p = o.hasOwnProperty(byProp);
      if(byVal === null){
        return p;
      }
      return p && byVal === o[byProp];
    });
  }
  this.getTech = (byProp, byVal = null)=>{
    return this.courses.technology.filter(o=>{
      let p = o.hasOwnProperty(byProp);
      if(byVal === null){
        return p;
      }
      return p && byVal === o[byProp];
    });
  }
  this.getAll = (byProp, byVal = null)=>{
    const m = this.getMath(byProp, byVal), s = this.getSpanish(byProp, byVal), t = this.getTech(byProp, byVal);
    return {math:m, spanish:s, technology:t}
  }
}
const courses = {
  math:[{id:1,level_id:1,requirement:'1 Credit'}, {id:2,level_id:2,requirement:'2 Credits'}],
  spanish:[{id:2,level_id:2,requirement:'2 Credits'}, {id:5,level_id:1,requirement:'5 Credits'}],
  technology:[{id:3,level_id:1,requirement:'2 Credits'}, {id:2,level_id:2,requirement:'2 Credits'}]
}
const cm = new CourseMaster(courses);
console.log(cm.getAll('level_id', 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the entries by their `level_id` (within the values) and then map their course name (key).

Additionally, I changed "Spanish" to level 2, to make sure it does not return.

**Note:** Since your object is nested within an array you can destruct the object then convert it into entries.

```js
let courses = [{
   math       : [ { id: 1, level_id: 1, requirement: '1 Credit'  } ],
   spanish    : [ { id: 5, level_id: 2, requirement: '5 Credits' } ],
   technology : [ { id: 3, level_id: 1, requirement: '2 Credits' } ]
}];

const findCoursesWhereLevelIdEquals = ([ courses ], id) =>
  Object.entries(courses)
    .filter(([ , [ { level_id } ] ]) => level_id === id)
    .map(([ courseName ]) => courseName);

console.log(findCoursesWhereLevelIdEquals(courses, 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```